# Нужна помощь в JS пирамиде

Tags: javascript

всем привет! нужно сделать вот такую пирамиду на JS

```html
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

написал такой код

```js
for(var i = 1;i <= 9; ++i) {
 for(var j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
  document.write(' '+j+' '); 
 }
 document.write('<br>'); 
};
```

и не могу разобраться как зациклить цифры внутри каждой строчки. буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: не делайте document.write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выводи текущую `i`  `j` раз и все получится

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
    document.write(' ' + i + ' ');
  }
  document.write('<br>');
};
```

Comment: спасибо!!! ты спас мою жизнь =))))))